# How can I calculate the number of metrics by unique labels without specifying a label in Prometheus/Grafana?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana, metrics

Because all URLs are dynamic, I cannot specify a specific URL when I group labels. Because every time a unique URL can appear.

Here's an example from metrics.

```
16:00:00
http_trace{method="GET",status="404",uri="/actuator/conditions/777",} 1.0
http_trace{method="GET",status="200",uri="/actuator/conditions",} 3.0
http_trace{method="GET",status="200",uri="/actuator/test",} 3.0
http_trace{method="GET",status="200",uri="/actuator/beans",} 3.0

16:00:30
http_trace{method="GET",status="404",uri="/actuator/conditions/777",} 4.0
http_trace{method="GET",status="200",uri="/actuator/conditions",} 2.0
http_trace{method="GET",status="200",uri="/actuator/test",} 6.0
http_trace{method="GET",status="200",uri="/actuator/beans123",} 7.0
```

How can I make Promethus or Grafana Query - So that I get that number.?

```
uri="/actuator/conditions/777" -> 5.0
uri="/actuator/conditions" -> 5.0
uri="/actuator/test" -> 9.0
uri="/actuator/beans" -> 3.0
uri="/actuator/beans123" -> 7.0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to calculate a **sum of metric values** grouped by some label:

```
sum(http_trace) by (uri)
```

This will give you the following result:

```
{uri="/actuator/conditions/777"} 5.0
{uri="/actuator/conditions"} 5.0
{uri="/actuator/test"} 9.0
{uri="/actuator/beans"} 3.0
{uri="/actuator/beans123"} 7.0
```

If you want to get the **number of time-series** (=how many **metrics** are there), grouped by `uri`  :

```
count(http_trace) by (uri)
```

And the result will be:

```
{uri="/actuator/conditions/777"} 1.0
{uri="/actuator/conditions"} 1.0
{uri="/actuator/test"} 1.0
{uri="/actuator/beans"} 1.0
{uri="/actuator/beans123"} 1.0
```

This shows how many metrics with unique label sets are there, grouped by `uri` label.

Comment: sum(http_trace) by (uri)
Thanks. Works, but not entirely correct. If I choose an interval of 2 hours, then I see as I want to see. That is, as it should be. If I choose a day or several days interval, it shows something completely different.

Comment: @JDev you might want to add `increase()` function to calculate the delta over a time period. That would be `sum(increase(http_trace[2d])) by (uri)`.

Comment: Thanks. And what is the default interval then?
But for some reason I don't understand why I am getting non-full numbers as a result, for example (13.5 or 4.5)

Comment: @JDev the default is no interval, that is current or last metrics. Metrics can disappear over time (if the exporter restarted or go offline) and that's why you had that strange result with a long range. As for `increase()` function behaviour, it works like `rate[interval]` multiplied by the number of seconds in the interval. This is explained in the documentation: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase

Comment: I have read the documentation several times already, the concept is a bit hard to understand. I understand that there are no metrics for some period. but I do not understand why it simply does not take those metrics that exist and does not sum them up.

Comment: @JDev Okay, let's try in other words. `sum(http_trace) by (uri)` gives you a sum of the metrics available **at the time**. When you put that on a graph, there will be several time points which define **the time**. And so you get a glimpse on what was there at each time point. With `increase()` you query not only current metrics, but __all metrics over the period defined in square brackets__. This repeats each time point on a graph and it may show metrics that were previously but not present any more.